# Javascript - How to execute function/statements selectively

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this is the best way to name this question but I have the following code which does not like to run in strict mode. I need to set the contents/statements of the `runstatementshere()` function,  depending on the `if` condition. Then `runstatementshere()` will run as part of another function and be part of that scope.

```
    if (i == true) {

        function runstatementshere() {

            // multiline commands
        };

    }

    else {

        function runstatementshere() {

        }

    }

    function somecode() {

        runstatementshere();

    }
```

Comment: Why not put the `if` statement inside the `runstatementshere` function?

Comment: Use  a function expression to assign a function to a variable declared in a higher scope rather than a function declaration.   Then, you can assign a different function implementation to the variable depending upon your `if` statement.

Comment: You should never define a function inside a conditional

Comment: Because `somecode()` needs to run many times so I thought calling a function in there via `runstatementshere();` is faster than having an `if` evaluation all the time, be it a simple one.  And I set my `runstatementshere();` content beforehand just once.

Comment: There's no real need to consider one over the other in this case due to speed. If you start micro managing your code like this, you will never finish it. The speed benefits (if any) are negligible at best

Comment: i see..........

Answer (score 0):

[Read this answer first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn#answer-336868)

Function declarations seem to be allowed in but hoisted within the containing block. I'm not sure if this is defined behaviour, but Chrome and Firefox act that way.

They behave that way because if the two functions were hoisted within the scope of the `if` statement, the latter would always win.

Anyway, to solve your issue, use function expressions.

```js
"use strict";

var runstatementshere;
if (true) {
  runstatementshere = function() { console.log("a"); }
} else {
  runstatementshere = function() { console.log("b"); }
}

function somecode() {
  runstatementshere();
}

somecode();
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach would be:

```js
function firstFunction() {
  console.log(1);
}

function secondFunction() {
  console.log(2);
}

function somecode() {
  if (i) {
    firstFunction();
  } else {
    secondFunction();
  }
}

var i = false;

somecode();
```

But if you have a good reason not to use `if` inside `somecode()`, try this way of declaring functions.

The problem in your code is that you declare the same function twice in the same scope.

```js
var runstatementshere, i = false;

if (i == true) {
  runstatementshere = function() {
    console.log(1);
  };
} else {
  runstatementshere = function() {
    console.log(2);
  };
}

function somecode() {
  runstatementshere();
}

somecode();
```

Comment: You should never define a function inside a conditional

Comment: @CarlMarkham: And why is that?

Comment: Because they can cause inconsistencies and are not a part of ECMAScript .T

Comment: @CarlMarkham You should never use function declaration inside a conditional but why in you opinion one shouldn't use function expression? Expressions aren't hoisted.

Comment: There is no need. The conditional should be inside of the function. I can't think of any instance where you would need to make an entire function conditional. My opinion of course. Would gladly be proven wrong. https://gist.github.com/cjmarkham/790b62f782746bb9cdc17edfec6c0e8a

Comment: @CarlMarkham Maybe you're right although I'm usually careful with _I can't think of any instance_ :) Hope you appreciate my edit.

Answer (score -2):

This should compile in strict mode.. but is somehow nonsensical.. as it would be more logical to include a condition in the function body. But still you may have a good use for it.

```
(function(){

var myFunction = i ? function() {} : function () {};
function a()
{
  myFunction();
}}

)()
```

Rewirite it so you have a function constructor..

```
var myFunctionConstructor = function(i) {

     return i ? function() {} : function () {};
}


var myFunction = myFunctionConstructor(false);
myFunction(); // first function called
myFunction = myFunctionConstructor(true);
myFunction(); // second function called
```

Comment: the function body of 'somecode()' runs many times so I don't want an IF in there. I want my IF outside of 'somecode()' .

Comment: @Zertix.net - It would be unusual if a single `if` in a function makes any difference.

Comment: @jfriend00 it would meke sense for an factory constructor.

Comment: factory constructor. .. sure if I knew what that was :)